# Ubuntu server not working

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

For some reason I can never get Ubuntu server to install , I’ve burned the iso image for the server multiple times With different formats and I can still never get to the language menu for the actual setup of it. I’m not sure why it won’t work cause I’ve literally tried everything and I meet all the requirements

Comment: To understand what's happened, more information is needed. Which hardware, which iso image you use? Is your machine able to boot from the external iso image? Maybe the disk, you tried to install ubuntu is fault .... and so on.

Comment: You've not provided any actual release details (*this matters esp. with install media if you're asking about a release >= 20.10*) nor how your write the ISO to your media (*that matters, including what software & version of software especially if using a non-clone write*).  Did you verify the ISO?  did the media verification complete? (*using method appropriate for your unstated release*)